# Is it possible to insert and filter icons / images together with cells in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, icons

I'm using Icons (which are basically graphics/images) in my Excel Sheet (Office 365). I figured that resizing the icon to the cell will "lock" it to the cell (allowing to copy/cut the icon with the cell). But when I filter the corresponding cells, the icon will move to another cell.

**How can I insert the icon in such a way that I can filter the icon with the cell?** (make it disappear when the cell disappears)

Here an example: The icons are locked in their corresponding cells and will move with the cells:

[image: the icons are locked to the cells]

However when I filter the cells, the icons stay visible and will move to different cells. I'd like to filter the icons as well...

[image: when filtering the icons move out of the cells]

Answer (score 1):

The solution lies with the Graphic options, where you need to set it to **"Move and size with cells"**. Apparently, by default, when resizing (locking) it to a cell, it gets the "Move but don't size with cells" property. With **Right-click -> Format Graphic** you can change this property.

[image: Format Graphic options: "Move and size with cells"]